# find rss feeds using good feed api

Tags: rss

```
This is my code, I want to find all the rss feeds present in But this is not working, can some one help me in this.
```

When I try to do execute this, it gives a blank page. Please help me getting this sorted.

I found the similar code for parsing rss feeds, I have just modified it, I assumed it should work. But id does not work for me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
  /// Here is the place I give my site name
  var feed = new google.feeds.findFeeds("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/");
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
  /// This is div where rss feed come and display in UI
<div id="feed"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm Check below code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Google Feed</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("feeds", "1");
    function initialize() {
    // Change your code with 
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss");
    // Because, findFeeds is a Callback method which is filter the result after feed query complete.
    // Second thing you are using normal website URL not feed url. So, change your URL too
    /// Here is the place I give my site name
    var feed = new google.feeds.findFeeds("http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/");  
    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var container = document.getElementById("feed");
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.appendChild(document.createTextNode((i+1) + ': ' + entry.title));
                container.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4> This is div where rss feed come and display in UI </h4>
<div id="feed">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Suggestion:**

> **First:**
>   Use Feed instead of findFeeds
>
> **Second:**
>   Use RSS URL

Comment: which rss URl are you talking about, I am trying to get all the RSS URL's present in timesofindia.indiatimes.com site